# How to follow parent_id through mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree, parent-child

I have a mysql table that represents a pseudo directory system:

```
CREATE TABLE `file_directories` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When a user is browsing this system our function receives a path that is made up of entries from the `name` column.

So, something like `first/child of first/grandchild` or `second/child of second/grandchild` would be a valid path and would look like this in the database.

```
/----------------------------------------------------\
| id | parent_id | name            | level | created |
|----|-----------|-----------------|-------|---------|
| 1  | NULL      | First           | 1     | ...     |
| 2  | 1         | Child of First  | 2     | ...     |
| 3  | 2         | Grandchild      | 3     | ...     |
| 4  | NULL      | Second          | 1     | ...     |
| 5  | 4         | Child of Second | 2     | ...     |
| 6  | 5         | Grandchild      | 3     | ...     |
\----------------------------------------------------/
```

Now currently if I want to list a directories children my process is this:

```
$path = 'first/child of first'; // demo data
$path = explode('/', $path); //array('first', 'child of first');
$level = count($path);
$name = end($path);

//query is not actually built like this, it uses the Codeigniter Active Records library
//but this is effectively the end result,
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `file_directories` WHERE `name` = '$name' AND `level` = $level";

///etc
```

Which works fine, until we deal with the `grandchild` directories, which have the same name and exist at the same level.

The directory structure enforces only one directory can exist with the same `parent_id` and `name` but same `name`'d directories with different `parent_id`'s can exist on the same `level`.

I cannot change what data I am passed, so the only way I can think of to do this is to start at the root node, and loop down doing multiple queries to find the correct child.

So, for the grandchild of second, the queries would be.

```
$parent_id = NULL;
foreach($path as $seg){
    $id = SQL: SELECT `id` FROM `file_directories` WHERE `name` = '$seg' AND `parent_id` = (IS NULL for root node) $parent_id;
}

//Get the actual node
$node = SQL: SELECT `*` FROM `file_directories` WHERE `id` = '$id';
```

But, that's a lot of queries, so, without changing what data I am given, is there a better way of tracing through the tree? or selecting the correct node?

Comment: Is the # of levels enforced? If so, you could self join the query using the parent id.

Answer (score 1):

learn the about wonders of recursive functions:
This code is bit simplified.

```
function select_child($node_id, $level, $target_level) {
  if(SELECT new_node_id WHERE parent_id = $node_id)
    if($level = $target_level) {
      return($new_node);
    } else {
      $results->add(select_child($new_node_id, ($level +1), $target_level);
    }
  } else {
    return(NULL);
  }
}
```

this function loops through the children of the given node until it finds a "leaf" (node without child) or it reaches the targeted level. if you are working with trees, most of your functions have to be recursive (calling themself until a specified condition is matched).

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I was getting at, but I don't like having to do that many queries is what I was getting annoyed at, I imagine I could pull the whole structure down from the database, and play with it in arrays, but that could get huge...

Comment: right. Don't worry. SELECT queries are really fast. And if you the same data again, it is likely that the DB has cached these Data. (e.g. stored this part of your datatable in RAM) so the performance is nearly the same as reading from an array... if you are experincing performace problems you have two options: Throw some Hardware at the Problem :) or cache the results of the recursive function in a second table. (what does not make any sense for small apps.)

Comment: To spped up the DB you may also set new index on both cols. this improves performance by a factor 10-15 :D